# (Easy one) Alter xml schema collection on sql server to modify an element's attribute

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, collections, schema

I have the following xml schema named XsdContacts(pretty simple actually)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="contact">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
<xs:element name="position" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
<xs:element name="phone1" nillable="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:unsignedInt">
<xs:attribute name="idtipo" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="phone2" nillable="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:unsignedInt">
<xs:attribute name="idtipo" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I want to alter lines 12 and 21, I want to add a Default to that attribute. The thing is that I tried to do it with the alter xml schema collection but it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at chapter 14 in [The Art of XSD SQL Server Schema Collections](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/entrypage/xsd-0409). You think you need to drop the schema collection and recreate it again and before you do that you need to remove any bindings to the schema.

Comment: Yeah that's the way I'm doing it, but it's a headache, I thought there was an easy way using the alter statement, well thanks!